# Visual Studio field encapsulation position

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, encapsulation

I have a little problem and I don't find a solution for it. I use Visual Studio 2015 for C#-Developement. And usually I use `CTRL R + E` to encapsulate a field. I was used to a behaviour from former Visual Studio Versions, where the generated property appeared right below the private member. Now, in Visual Studio 2015, it's being generated anywhere in the code (can't even tell you which rules it uses for that).

Is there a posibility to set this behaviour back to the one of former Visual Studio versions?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: VS2015 moved to Roslyn for both compilation and code-gen, so this behavioural change is probably related to that. I suggest you file an Issue on the Roslyn github account page. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Comment: Is that a regular or a Resharper shortcut?

Comment: I would say that it's not "who knows where" but at the top of the class...

Comment: It's the normal shortcut Visual Studio offers for that. It's the same like right-clicking on the private member -> quick actions -> encapsulate field.

Comment: - Plain Visual Studio appears to insert the new property after the LAST public property in your code file. Does not appear to be configurable.

- If you are using R# the inserted property is placed according to your Resharper/Options/Code Editing/C#/File layout. If you are not using automatic layout formatting you could empty the layout and your property will be inserted above the field. (Not sure if this is answer material because I don't think I can solve your problem.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately that's no solution. I don't understand, why Microsoft changed that and/or didn't make in configurable. But at least I now know, that it's not configurable.
I think I will change to using the `prop`-Snippet.